# NPE when instantiate a Dialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

i'm trying to instantiate a Dialog in my Activity.

```
public void createOptionsMenu() {
    Log.e("ActivityContext null?","" + myActivity.this);
    myOptionsDialog = new Dialog(myActivity.this); //throwsNPE
    myOptionsDialog.setContentView(R.layout.options_dialog);
    myOptionsDialog.show();
}
```

Due to the Log.e which you can see above i know that my `activity-context` is not null!

```
12-21 15:17:15.466: E/ActivityContext null?(3774): com.android.myproject.myActivity@41fd9af0
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I think to Problem is that i call `createOptionsMenu()` from a different class which only has the `ApplicationContext` from `myActivity`. If so, how can i create my Dialog without passing the `ActivityContext` to the other class which calls `createOptionsMenu`.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update:**

`12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:140)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:103)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:154)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:131)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.android.myproject.myActivity.createOptionsMenu(myActivity.java:798)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.android.myproject.WorkerClass$2.onItemLongClick(WorkerClass.java:448)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performLongPress(AbsListView.java:2883)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.widget.AbsListView$CheckForLongPress.run(AbsListView.java:2833)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5338)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
12-21 15:17:15.469: E/AndroidRuntime(3774):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`

Instantiate Activity:

```
myActivity myActivity_ = new myActivity();
                WeakReference<myActivity> myWeakActivity = new WeakReference<myActivity>(myActivity_);
                myWeakActivity.get().createOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: Post the exception stacktrace and how you're initializing `myActivity`.

Comment: @laalto i've updated my question. What do you mean initializing? myActivity? It's my `MainActivity`. I'm relatively new to Android so i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I mean how `myActivity` variable gets a value and from where. From the stacktrace it's apparent you've instantiating your activity with `new` which is something you should never do.

Comment: @laalto ok i think i know what you mean. Updated my question. If i do so i always put in a weakreferences. I didn't have any Problems with Memory leaks in the past doing so. But i'm sure you can improve my know how. Why this is wrong and what is a better way. :)

Comment: Never instantiate an activity class with `new`. Use an `Intent` or pass around a reference to an existing activity.

Comment: @laalto ok and what is the Problem when i create it with new and i put it in weak reference? And how can i solve my Dialog issue. :/ Just for understanding

Comment: It's not initialized for anything you'd use an `Activity` for.

Comment: @laalto now you have lost me..

Comment: You should name your `myActivity` class starting with upper case, because it is a class, not a variable. Like `MyActivity`.

Comment: First, the right way to start an Activity is different. Check http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html. I think the right way to do what you want is by using an `Interface`. Then, all the Activities that you want to be able to implement that method implement that `Interface`.

Comment: @joao2fast4u ok that's fine but i don't want to start my `myActivity` agin because it's already running. `WorkerClass` is just an `AsyncTask`. So why to start the whole activity again?. Secondly i only have the `ApplicationContext` in my `WorkerClass`. So this won't solve my Issue. I don't understand why i get a NPE when MyActivity.this is not null?? Thank you for your Response. Can you give me a link for an example of using a Interface in that way. as i said i'm relatively new to android

Comment: You just need a `Context` to start a Dialog. If you want to start your Dialog from within your Activity, just call createOptionsMenu();

Comment: @joao2fast4u i did and i get NPE as shown above in the question. And from what i know is that you Need the `ActivityContext` not the `ApplicationContext` for a Dialog and that's why i call it on in my Activity and pass the `ActivityContext` which is not null but i get and NPE at that line. You are both saying that you should never initialize an activity with new, but i wasn't able to get one reason why this is bad. So i'm not learning something i want to know why it is bad and why i'm getting a NPE while my `ActivityContext` is `not` null.

Comment: @MMike You have to show more code, namely on the place you are making your call to createOptionsMenu(); Do you have only one Activity? You should use an Intent because it is the official and the recommended way.

Comment: @joao2fast4u hey Joao i showed the code where i make the call to oncreateOptionsMenu please see bottom of my question. Yes i have only one, as i said the other class is just a asynctask :)

Comment: Could you please show your XML dialog layout? What if you use just new Dialog(this)?

Comment: @joao2fast4u i already solved it by passing the `Activity-Context`. The Problem was i created a new `Object` of my Activity. So the "real" ActivityContext isn't valid in the new Object of my ActivityContext. But thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was the Context. As i created a new Object of my Activity the old Activity isn't valid "inside" the new Object.

The soltuion was to simply pass the `Activity-Context` to `createOptionsMenu` and then do this:

```
MyActivity myActivity_ = (MyActivity) context;
```

Then you have a reference to the resources you really want.

Hope it helps somebody.